# Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON

Tags: mongoid, carrierwave, gridfs

I'm following [GridFS with Mongoid and CarrierWave](http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/) to implement a simple has_many polymorphic relationship and when I attempt to create a new user, with an avatar, through nested attribute assignment, I get:

```rb
Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON
```

Has anyone else encountered this? I noticed a few individuals posted replies to the "GridFS with Mongoid and CarrierWave" article but I was unable to find anyone with an answer.

```rb
# app/models/asset.rb
class Asset
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    mount_uploader :file, AssetUploader

    field :name, type: String

    referenced_in :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    references_one :avatar, as: :attachable

    accepts_nested_attributes :avatar
end
```

```rb
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.grid_fs_connection = Mongoid.database
    config.storage = :grid_fs
    config.grid_fs_access_url = "/images"
end
```

```rb
# app/uploaders/asset_uploader.rb
class AssetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base  
end
```

```rb
# app/views/users/new.html.haml
= semantic_form_for(@user, html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
    = f.inputs do
    = f.semantic_fields_for :avatar do |af|
        = af.input :file, as: :file
    = f.buttons do
        = f.commit_button "Upload"
```

Comment: If you run into this, make sure you've named your form fields correctly. The above code works just fine, assuming there are no mismatched input field names and association names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about naming the fields.

Had the same issue with mongo_mapper and a field I have renamed on the form.

The form fields have to have the same names of the fields in you model.

Comment: in the given example don't names match?